# Using attributes in a class that implements an interface in another class

Tags: java, variables, methods, interface

Hi everyone i am trying to use the attributes in my `Fish class` which implements an an interface called `Catchable` , in my  `Fisher class` , is this possible, or is there some part of interfaces that I am not understanding. Because i thought we were allowed to use the attributes in a class that has been implemented by an interface, in another class, however i keep errors saying:

```
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable weight
  location: variable item of type Catchable

Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable size
  location: variable item of type Catchable

Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable weight
  location: variable item of type Catchable .
```

Any help or advice on this is appreciated!

If needed, here is my `Catchable` interface:

```
public interface Catchable
{
  public float getWeight();
  public boolean isDesirableTo(Fisher f);
}
```

my `Fish class` which implements the `Catchable` interface

```
public abstract class Fish implements Catchable
{
    // Any fish below this size must be thrown back into the lake
    public static int  THROW_BACK_SIZE = 18; 
    public static float WEIGHT_LIMIT = 10;

    protected float weight;
    protected int  size;

    public Fish(int aSize, float aWeight) 
    {
        size = aSize;
        weight = aWeight;
    }


    public boolean isDesirableTo(Fisher f) 
    {
        if(canKeep() && f.numThingsCaught < f.LIMIT && this.weight + f.sumOfWeight < WEIGHT_LIMIT)
        {
          return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }

    public abstract boolean canKeep(); 

    public int getSize() { return size; }
    public float getWeight() { return weight; }


    public String toString () 
    {
        return ("A " + size + "cm " + weight +  "kg " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

}
```

and lastly my `Fisher class`

```
import java.util.*;

public class Fisher     
{
  private String name;
  private Catchable [] thingCaught;
  public int numThingsCaught; 
  private int keepSize;
  public float  sumOfWeight;
  public static int LIMIT = 10;

  public String getName() 
  {
    return this.name;
  }

  public int getNumThingsCaught()
  {
    return this.numThingsCaught;
  }

  public int getKeepSize()
  {
    return this.keepSize;
  }


  public Fisher(String n, int k)
  {
    name = n;
    keepSize = k;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return(this.name + " with " + this.numThingsCaught + " fish");
  }
  private ArrayList<Catchable> thingsCaught = new ArrayList<Catchable>();


  public void keep(Catchable item) 
  {
    if(this.numThingsCaught < LIMIT)
    {
      thingsCaught.add(item);
      numThingsCaught++;
      sumOfWeight += item.weight;
    }
  }

  public boolean likes(Catchable item)
  {
    if(item.size >= this.keepSize)
    {
      return true;
    }

    else 
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public void listThingsCaught() 
  {
    System.out.println(this.toString());

    for(Catchable item : thingsCaught)
    {
      System.out.println(item.toString());
    }
  }

  public void goFishingIn(Lake lake)
  {
    Catchable item = lake.catchSomething();

    if(likes(item))
    {
      this.keep(item);
    }
    else
    {
      lake.add(item);
    }
  }

  public void giveAwayFish(Fisher fisher, Lake lake)
  {
    for(Catchable item : thingsCaught)
    {
      if(fisher.likes(item))
      {
        fisher.keep(item);
      }
      else
      {
        lake.add(item);
      }
      sumOfWeight -= item.weight;
    }
    thingsCaught.clear();
    this.numThingsCaught = 0;

  }

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have a background in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are the following lines:

- `keep()`:

  ```
  sumOfWeight += item.weight;
  ```
- `likes()`:

  ```
  if(item.size >= this.keepSize)
  ```
- `giveAwayFish()`:

  ```
  sumOfWeight -= item.weight;
  ```

In every case, `item` is of type `Catchable`, and `Catchable` doesn't have `size` or `weight`fields. What you have to do is call `item.getWeight()` instead of `item.weight` and add a `getSize()` method to `Catchable`, and call `item.getSize()` instead of `item.size`:

- `Catchable`:

  ```
  public interface Catchable
  {
    public float getWeight();
    public int getSize();
    public boolean isDesirableTo(Fisher f);
  }
  ```
- `keep()`:

  ```
  sumOfWeight += item.getWeight();
  ```
- `likes()`:

  ```
  if(item.getSize() >= this.keepSize)
  ```
- `giveAwayFish()`:

  ```
  sumOfWeight -= item.getWeight();
  ```

You don't have to modify `Fish`, as it already implements `getSize()`.
And you should really use an IDE like Eclipse, because it can show you where your errors are in real time.

Answer (score 2):

Not every `Catchable` is a `Fish`, so, for example

```
public boolean likes(Catchable item)
{
    if(item.size >= this.keepSize)
...
```

will fail, because `Catchable` doesn't have a `size` member (it also can't have member variables because it's an interface). `item` is `Catchable` here, it's not `fish`.

When you're using an interface, you should only interact with the instance through the methods defined in the interface (or in interfaces that it extends).

Comment: so can you just move the size attribute into Catchable?

Comment: `Catchable` can't have a `size` attribute, but it can have a getter method `getSize()` that you would use instead of `size` in your `Fisher` class.

Answer (score 2):

In Java we usually call them "fields" not "attributes".

Anyways, there are a couple of issue. First, you declare `weight` (for example) as `protected` in `Fish`. This is the right thing to do here, but it means that `weight` is not accessible outside of `Fish`. So you would have to do this from a class outside of `Fish`:

```
void example (Fish fish) {
    // System.out.println(fish.weight); // <- not allowed, weight is protected
    System.out.println(fish.getWeight()); // <- ok, getWeight() is public
}
```

That's the point of providing a public getter like `getWeight()` in the `Catchable` interface in the first place (that and the fact that interfaces can't have non-static non-final member fields). The underlying implementation is hidden -- an object that implements `Catchable` might not have a `weight` field at all and might calculate a return value based on some completely different set of rules. But it doesn't matter, because you access it through `getWeight()`.

Secondly, the above doesn't make sense for a general `Catchable` anyways even if `Fish.weight` *was* `public`; `Catchable` does not have a field named `weight`. `Fish` does. So if you are accessing it through a reference of type `Catchable`, there's no `weight` anyways.

You *do* provide `Catchable.getWeight()`, however. That method is present in all `Catchable` types. So you would have to use that to access `weight`. So in your `Fisher` you could do:

```
void example (Catchable catchable) {
    // System.out.println(catchable.weight); // <- not allowed, Catchable has no weight
    System.out.println(catchable.getWeight()); // <- ok, getWeight() is public and is in Catchable
}
```

I highly suggest working through the official [Interfaces and Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) tutorial. It may familiarize you with a few of the concepts you are asking about.

---

**Added:**

It seems like you have a background in C# or another language with a similar concept of "attributes" - where you provide a getter/setter but syntactically you still refer to it directly by the attribute name (e.g. `fish.weight = 3` calls `fish.setWeight(3)` automatically).

This construct does not exist in Java. You can write getters/setters as member methods, and you call them, and that's all you get. There is no automatic calling of getters/setters on direct field access. You can have this:

```
class Example {
     public int field;
     public void setSomething (int x) { ... }
     public int getSomething () { ... }
}
```

And that's what you get. From that you can do this:

```
Example x = ...;
x.field = ...;
... = x.field;
x.setSomething(...);
... = x.getSomething();
```

But you cannot automatically do anything like this:

```
x.setField(...);
... = x.getField();
x.something = ...;
... = x.something;
```

So if you have a background in a language like that, that could be the source of your confusion. You will need to adjust. In Java you have to explicit; the language is noteworthy for its low amount of ambiguity and redundancy.

Comment: Hang on a second.  `Fish` is `abstract`.  You can't just do `new Fish()`.

Answer (score 1):

I see this dotted about in your code:

```
sumOfWeight += item.weight;
```

Slow down a moment here - you're not using a concrete instance of a class; you're referring to the interface instead.  You'll observe that the interface doesn't have a field for `weight`, hence your compilation failure.

If you want to adhere to using the interface, then you need to change a few things.

- Add a method `getWeight()` to your interface.

  ```
  public float getWeight();
  ```
- Remove the `abstract` declaration from your `Fish` class (that will only serve to hurt and confuse you).
- Then, when you want to perform that summation operation, you can:

  ```
  sumOfWeight += item.getWeight();
  ```

Comment: thanks for the response but doesn't my interface already have a getWeight() method?

Comment: Yes, but you're not using it.  I believe I picked that as the quickest example I could see (since it does have it defined); you would want to also create other methods in your interface that rely on a field as opposed to a getter in your interface, too.